# Script Debugging in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, internet-explorer

I'm really interested which way you guys use to effectivly debug a large (let's say 1000 lines and more) javascript in IE7/8/9.

I'm so sick of reading a message like 'error in line 9328789237498" or "line 1" which
totally makes no sense. No error description.

There must be something like Firebug? please? :)

Kind Regards

--Andy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE 8 comes with Developer Tools, which is similar (but not quite as powerful) as firebug.

See: [Discovering Internet Explorer Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I know about the dev toolbar, but does it change this wierd behavior from IE script error console? Does it really show you where javascript error occurs?

Comment: Yes, I have used it myself to track down errors that were only occurring in IE.

Answer (score 4):

Checkout the [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E59C3964-672D-4511-BB3E-2D5E1DB91038&displaylang=en) (more information at [Internet Explorer Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628%28VS.85%29.aspx)). If you want Firebug, you can try out the (not as powerful) [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

Comment: Yes, I've used it to track errors in IE. It's not as powerful as Firebug, but on IE even a little bit helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio to debug Javascript as well.  Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced -> Uncheck the boxes for disabling script debugging.  Then run with Visual Studio attached to the IExplore process.